# Problem of Xunit.net TestOutputHelper not working with C# Library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, xunit.net

**TEST ENVIRONMENT:**

.NET 6 console app with a class library in C#
Visula Studio 2022
Packages:
Xunit 2.4.2
Xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.3

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

I was testing output messages to Xunit test result using TestOutputHelper (provided in XUnit.sdk)

The output message works properly when unit tests against objects in console app: XunitCollection.

But, it does not work when testing against objects in class library: ServiceManager (see details in the test output at the end). There is no compiler error.  The ServiceManager was added as project reference in ServiceManagerTest.

Why it works when testing against C# console app, but not when testing against class library?

**TESTING CODE:**

----- Class Randomizer to be tested in IBRARY: SeviceManager ----

```
{
    public class Randomizer
    {
        public int RndNumber { get; private set; }
        private Random _rnd;
        public Randomizer()
        {
            _rnd = new Random();
            RndNumber = _rnd.Next();
        }

        public void RandomWithRange(int lower, int upper)
        {
            RndNumber = _rnd.Next(lower, upper);
        }
    }
}
```

------ Unit Test Case ------

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace ServiceManagerTests
{
    public class OutputMessageTest
    {
        private TestOutputHelper _outHelper;

        public OutputMessageTest(TestOutputHelper outHelper)
        {
            _outHelper = outHelper;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void WriteMessageTest()
        {
            _outHelper.WriteLine("First Message added to the test result");

            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

------ Output from Failed Test ------

```
﻿ ServiceManagerTests.OutputMessageTest.WriteMessageTest
  Source: OutputMessageTest.cs line 16
  Duration: 1 ms

  Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestOutputHelper outHelper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be injecting the interface [`ITestOutputHelper`](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output), not the concrete class `TestOutputHelper` into your test fixtures, i.e.

```
private ITestOutputHelper _outHelper;

public OutputMessageTest(ITestOutputHelper outHelper)
{
    _outHelper = outHelper;
}

[Fact]
public void MyFact()
{
    _outHelper.WriteLine("Foo");
}
```

XUnit won't resolve the concrete class, and will likely give you the run time error:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestOutputHelper outputHelper

Comment: Thanks for the given solution.  That fixed the problem.